# How to append a scene from an existing .blend file to the current .blend file?

Tags: python, append

I just want to append a scene (named "fred" which is the ONLY scene in the file) to the existing open blend file. Seems like this should be easy, but I can't find out how to do this. So, after the append there should be two scenes: the orignal one and a new one named "fred".

I know the name and location of the file and the scene I want appended.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry, but I already looked at that message and it is not the answer. Please reopen.

Comment: @Batfinger The link you refer to deals with collections and objects. I'm trying to figure out how to import SCENES. Can you help?

Comment: I have no issue doing this with File > Append > (select .blend with "fred" scene) > Scene Folder > "fred" scene > Append, then the scene is available in the top of the window in the Scene section.

Comment: The [link to docs in dupe answer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html)  first example **append scene**.  Surely it is unnecessary to have a separate question on how to link / append  each data block type.. How to append a mesh, how to append an object, how to append a lattice, how to append a camera, how to append an armature...

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for the link to the docs.